# How to open new page on node click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple example of `p:tree`.

```
<p:tree id="tree" styleClass="treeskin" value="#{TreeViewController.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" animate="true"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{TreeViewController.selectedNode}" highlight="true">

    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeSelect}" update=":treeform:outputComponent"/>
    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeExpand}" />
    <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeCollapse}" />

    <p:treeNode styleClass="treeskin">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

I'm interested is it possible somehow when I click on a node to open a new page. I found that using `onNodeClick` I can open a new page using JavaScript. But if it's possible I want to send hidden value which I will use as a key later.
What are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You could try embedding an `<h:link/>` in the `<p:treeNode/>`. Use the following construct

```
<h:link value="#{node}" outcome="destination?includeViewParams=true">
   <f:param name="theParam" value="#{node.property}"/>
</h:link>
```

The `includeViewParams=true` bit is going to ensure the parameter you're trying to pass makes it across the request to the next page